# Move artifacts files and folders to a one (release) folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What is the best approach/ plugin to move multiple files and folders to a new release folder? (I'm using the Jenkinsfile pipeline)

Case:

The next files/ folders need to be available in the release package:

```
Folder1\\SubFolder1\\bin\\Release\\*.dll
Folder1\\SubFolder1\\bin\\Release\\*.exe"
Folder1\\SubFolder1\\bin\\Release\\Resources\\**\\*.xml
Folder1\\SubFolder1\\bin\\Release\\**\\*.dll
```

I'm using the '`archiveArtifacts artifacts`' command to create the artifacts. This seems to work, but I would like to create **one** folder which contains above defined files and folders.

Final *expected* result:

```
ReleaseFolder    
    -test1.dll    (part of Folder1\\SubFolder1\\bin\\Release\\*.dll)
    -test2.dll    (part of Folder1\\SubFolder1\\bin\\Release\\*.dll)
    -SubXmlFolder (part of Folder1\\SubFolder1\\bin\\Release\\Resources\\**\\*.xml - note: the \\**\\ is the SubXmlFolder)
      -test3.xml  (part of SubXmlFolder)
      -test4.xml  (part of SubXmlFolder)
     -en-GB       (part of Folder1\\SubFolder1\\bin\\Release\\**\\*.dll - note: the \\**\\ is the en-GB folder)
       -test5.dll (part of the en-GB folder)
```

Comment: hi - you might want crosspost this at DevOps SE

Comment: @J.Doe Do I need to duplicate/ copy this question to DevOps SE, or does SO provide another way to crosspost questions?

Comment: this I do not know what is best technically, in doubt just duplicate and cross-link; I just meant to say, you might get an answer faster there on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

File Operations Plug providing many features for files and folders.

link: https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-operations

Comment: That plugin doesn't seem to have been updated for Jenkins2 (jenksinfile, as asked by OP), and the documentation doesn't offer a jenkinsfile DSL syntax for it. Please share that syntax if it's available from elsewhere ?

Comment: It is offering Jenkinsfile DSL syntax. after installing the plugin some Jenkins restart required for this. after restart you can find this plugin in the pipeline DSL syntax. append the following to the jenkins URL to find the DSL syntax for any plugin... URL: http://<JenkinsURL>/job/PipelinePrompt/pipeline-syntax/